# Table/Form design; Record/user has Multiple addresses, selected the address that is the contact

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

Looking for advice as to the correct method of solving this design issue

I have a table for a profile / record (tblProfile), each profile can have more than one address / property (tblProp)

I have a form for adding a profile, and a seperate form to add an address.

What would be the correct method for allowing the selection of one an address as a contact address?
Would it be advisable to use a third table to store the user ID and contact address ID, or use a field in tblProp.
What type of form design would be needed?

I imagine this is pretty basic database design / theory, but im having a bit of difficulty figuring this out.

Thanks in advance for any help any one may be able to provide

Cheers
Noel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having gone through this, I think that an address status field is the best bet. This will allow you to choose whether the address is the main address, a former address, etc. In fact, depending on your set-up, it can be useful to have two classification fields, the one just described and address type, which would be home, work etc.

Another point - I have found it useful in some circumstances to write the key for the main address to the persons table.

Comment: Cheers Remou. What would be the correct way, using your method, to ensure that only one address can be selected as a contact address? So when changing an address status to contact, the previous address used as contact details would have its status changed automatically?

Comment: If each person can only have one contact address, store it in the main table. If the address key matches the main table key, then it is a contact address.

Comment: By main table you mean the table with the users details, tblProfile?

Comment: Yes. If a field (column) can occur only once, tblProfile is a good place to keep it.